# How can I use this.props as different instances?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this two subcomponents: Step1 and Step2 and I want to show on a separate vertical menu which of those components are active. They are active when isValid is true, isValidating is false and isSubmitting is false.
The vertical menu is represented by the Item components.

My problem is: How can I make a custom 
this.props property for each step? Right now if I complete the forms in Step1 both of the items will become active.

I tried this but it doesn't work. 
    
`step1Props = this.props;
step2Props = this.props;`

This is the code inside wizard:

```
render(){
  const { handleSubmit, errors, touched } = this.props;

  const items = [
    <Item
      key={0}
      step={0}
      active={
        !(
          this.props.isValid ||
          this.props.isValidating ||
          this.props.isSubmitting
        )
      }
    />,
    <Item
      key={1}
      step={1}
      active={
        !(
          !this.props.isValid ||
          this.props.isValidating ||
          this.props.isSubmitting
        )
      }
    />
  ];

  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      {this.props.currentStep == 0 && <Step1 {...this.props} />}
      {this.props.currentStep == 1 && <Step2 {...this.props} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you mean for each `Step` to have its own `{isValid, isValidating, isSubmitting}`, or do those props apply to the wizard as a whole? If the latter, what are the props that each `Step` actually needs?

Comment: @Andrew Schwartz I mean for each `Step` to have it's own `{isValid, isValidating, isSubmitting}`

Answer (score 0):

From your response to my comment above, looks like you want each `Step` to have its own `{isValid, validating, submitting}`. Currently you only have one value for each of these three vars; instead, you need to have something like an array of these values, one for each `Step`. That is, assuming this component is called `<Wizard>`, you could have the following.

```
const stepProps = [
  {isValid: false, isValidating: false, isSubmitting: false},
  {isValid: true,  isValidating: false, isSubmitting: false},
];

<Wizard steps={stepProps} ... />
```

Not sure where the values themselves are coming from in your application, but given your setup I am assuming they are passed down as props from another parent component.

Then, in the wizard jsx:

```
return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      {this.props.currentStep == 0 && <Step1 {...this.props.steps[0]} />}
      {this.props.currentStep == 1 && <Step2 {...this.props.steps[1]} />}
    </div>
  );
```

For the `Item`s, you'd have this (I'm refactoring the valid computation into a function for less code)

```
function itemIsActive(itemProps) {
  return itemProps.isValid &&
         !itemProps.isValidating &&
         !itemProps.isSubmitting;
}

const items = [
  <Item key={0} step={0} active={itemIsActive(this.props.steps[0]}>,
  <Item key={1} step={1} active={itemIsActive(this.props.steps[1]}>,
];
```